# WPF Styling setter's targetname to dependencyproperty's property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to set the `targetname` of a style setter to a dependency property's `Name` property. Not quite sure how to approach this.

> ```
> //Customcontrol's Generic.xaml
> <Style TargetType="{x:Type Controls:MyControl}">
>     <Setter Property="Template">
>         <Setter.Value>
>             <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Controls:MyControl}">
>                 <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
>                         BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
>                         BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
>                     <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
>                 </Border>
>             </ControlTemplate>
>         </Setter.Value>
>     </Setter>
>     <Setter TargetName="WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE" Property="Opacity" Value="0.75"/>
>
> </Style>
>
> // Dependency Property
> public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelToDisplayProperty  ...
>
> // In XAML that adds the custom control
> LabelToDisplay="{x:Reference Name=TitleLabel}"
> ```

Basically in the `TargetName` I would like to put the `name` of the object that `LabelToDisplay` property references.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can move that Opacity setter into LabelToDisplay object and  trigger it only when needed?

Maybe you can bind against LabelToDisplay in TargetName?

If not, there is last option I think, you'll make new DataTrigger against LabelToDisplay, and then you do:

```
<DataTrigger.EnterActions>

    Animation here

</DataTrigger.EnterActions>
```

You can set Target with animation easily. (Eg you don't need "Name" property at all, just give the object it needs)